# cljs is not defined in LightTable

Tags: javascript, clojurescript, lighttable

I connected my LightTable to Firefox using the script tag.

However, when I'm evaluating the form

```
(def a 5)
```

inside my cljs file, I get the following exception thrown out in Firefox:

```
ReferenceError: cljs is not defined

var exdata = cljs.core.ex_data(e);
```

at ws.js (line 121)

But the form

```
(js/alert "abc")
```

can be evaluated, and there's a window poped showing "abc", but there's none evaluation result shown in the LightTable.

Anyone can help me fix this? Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem.. I didn't include the cljs script file into the html file.

After including the cljs file inside the html, and run `lein cljsbuild [once|auto]` everything's ok..